# How to view the source code of wizardDialog in Eclipse?

Tags: plugins

I press Ctrl+Shift+T in Eclipse and try to view the source code of WizardDialog class, but error happens: Source not found, the JAR of this class file belongs to container 'External Plug-ins' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries...

Where can I get the source code? Any URL to download it?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing Eclipse Plugin source in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907201/importing-eclipse-plugin-source-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally has two solutions:

1. create a folder named sources under the same directory with the jar file, and put the source code into that folder. Then restart the eclipse.
2. Add the jar file into the classpath, then the attachment of the source code will be allowed.

Comment: You mean you don't have the source code? If the jar file is included in an open source project, download the source. If it is not, try some decompiler.